# Refresh controls in the ribbon tab for sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Can any one tell me the code to refresh the ribbon controls in the sharepoint 2010 ribbon bar, using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

RefreshCommandUI();

Link from MSDN blog site: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/02/17/using-refreshcommandui-with-the-server-ribbon.aspx